Метод setdefault
Решал задачку и не прошло решение,но потом решил ее и вернулся, чтобы разобраться,но пока не понял до конца.
Код №1:
text = 'footballcyberpunkextraterritorialityconversationalistblockophthalmoscopicinterdependencemamauserfff'

result = {}
for i in text:
    result.setdefault(i,0) + 1
  
print(result)

В задаче надо посчитать кол-во повтора букв и в этом коде метод setdefault добавляет в словарь result одни нули каждой букве, но не прибавляет 1(ну или не учитывает, хз).
код №2:
text = 'footballcyberpunkextraterritorialityconversationalistblockophthalmoscopicinterdependencemamauserfff'

result = {}
for i in text:
    result.setdefault(i)
  
print(result)

тут в ответе у всех букв значение None.
Код №3:
text = 'footballcyberpunkextraterritorialityconversationalistblockophthalmoscopicinterdependencemamauserfff'

result = {}
for i in text:
    result.setdefault(i) + 1
  
print(result)

Тут у нас появляется ошибка "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'" и мы узнаем, что нельзя сложить None и цифру 1,делаем вывод что цифра 1 видна, но в коде №1, она почему то не складывается с нулем.

В кодах 1 и 3 вы никуда не сохраняете результат сложения и он просто выбрасывается

setdefault(key, default=None) по умолчанию setdefault выставляет значение в None, отсюда у вас None и возникает в примерах 2 и 3.

Можно исправить так - в данном случае результат сложения используется, а не теряется
result[i] = result.setdefault(i, 0) + 1

Но более логично написать
result[i] = result.get(i,0) + 1

На мой взгляд, легче читается с проверкой:
for i in text:
    if i in result:
        result[i] += 1
    else:
        result[i] = 1

print(result)

Можно упростить с defaultdict (указывается тип value)
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(int)
for i in text:
    result[i] += 1

Ещё проще использовать Counter:
from collections import Counter
r = Counter(text)
print(r)


Два поиска ключа в словаре вместо одного — выглядит неоптимально (еее микрооптимизации)

(хотя если автор ограничится добавлением сохранения сложения словарь, то их тоже получится два...)

Но ведь result[i] = result.setdefault(i, 0) + 1 (или с get) тоже будет два поиска делать. Вот defaultdict может за одну операцию (по крайней мере, нам видимую) увеличить значение
